# Can't add NavigationController on TableView using UISplitView

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am having a little hard time here, forgive me if you think my problem is so easy for you.
I am trying to create app using `UISplitView`. The 1st View on the left is a `TableView` and the other one on the right is just a normal view.

This is my Code for in ***`AppDelegate.m`*** for `UISplitView`.

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "MasterViewController.h"
#import "DetailViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:        (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

MasterViewController *masterVC = [[MasterViewController alloc]init];
DetailViewController *detailVC = [[DetailViewController alloc]init];
UISplitViewController *splitVC = [[UISplitViewController alloc]init];
[splitVC setViewControllers:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:masterVC,detailVC,nil]];
[self.window setRootViewController:splitVC];

self.window.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Now, I want to add a Navigation Bar on the `TableView`, I just don't know how to add if I am using `SplitView`,but I can when I am using a single `TableView`.

This is my Code in ***`AppDelegate.m`*** using a single View Application that uses `TableView`. (This is working)

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "ViewController.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
self.viewController = [[ViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:nil];
//create UINavigationController
UINavigationController *nav = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.viewController];
self.window.rootViewController = nav;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
return YES;
}
```

Hope you can understand what I'm trying to say. I can't post images since i don't have enough reputation. AGAIN.. The question is "How can I add Navigation Controller in my `TableView` if I used `UISplitView`?"
Do you think it will be easy for me if I use `storyboards` instead of using two `XIB` files?Hope you can help me.

Thanks in advanced!

Answer (score 0):

try this code

in ***AppDelegate.h*** file

```
    UINavigationController *detailNavigationController;
    UINavigationController  *masterNavigationController;
    UISplitViewController  *HomeSpilitView;
    HomeSpilitViewController *HomeMster;
    HomeDetailsViewController *HomeDetailsViewControllers;
```

in ***AppDelegate.m*** file

```
     -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
    {
        self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];

        NSMutableArray *array = [NSMutableArray array];

                            HomeSpilitView = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init]autorelease];

                            HomeMster = [[HomeSpilitViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeSpilitViewController" bundle:nil];

                            masterNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:HomeMster] autorelease];
                            HomeMster.title=@"Title home";
                            masterNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:108/255.0 blue:61/255.0 alpha:0.1];
                            [array addObject:masterNavigationController];


                            HomeDetailsViewController *HomeDetailsViewControllers = [[HomeDetailsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"HomeDetailsViewController" bundle:nil];

                            detailNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:HomeDetailsViewControllers] autorelease];

                            detailNavigationController.navigationBar.tintColor =[UIColor colorWithRed:255/255.0 green:108/255.0 blue:61/255.0 alpha:0.1];
                            HomeDetailsViewControllers.title=@"details title";
                            HomeMster.objHomeDetailsViewcontroller=HomeDetailsViewControllers;
                            HomeSpilitView.delegate = HomeDetailsViewControllers;

                          [array addObject:detailNavigationController];

                          [HomeSpilitView setViewControllers:array];

                          [self.window setRootViewController:HomeSpilitView];
         [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
         return YES;
    }
```

Comment: I am having some errors. XCode doesn't seem to recognize `HomeSplitViewController`. Please explain how you did that, did you define it somewhere in other files? In `ViewController.h` maybe?